# Long swipe to delete in IOS tableview

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I implemented swipe to delete in IOS tableview ad it works fine in IOS 10 and IOS 11.

I can swipe the row, click on delete button and it works out. In IOS 11, I can do a long swipe to delete it whereas in IOS 10 when I try to do a long swipe to delete it does not work. I have to swipe and click on delete button explicitly. I tried this in IOS 10 simulator and not a real device.

Is it possible to get long swipe to delete working ion IOS 10 as well.

Comment: Long swipe to delete is an iOS 11 feature, if you want it in iOS 10 you have to make it yourself

Answer (score 2):

iOS 10 does not natively support this gesture, only iOS 11 does.

You'll have to implement your own solution, or use one of the 3rd-Party-Libraries out there that implement long swipe, such as https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell